# Split text in pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas table like this:

```
ID   | Tag
1    | up down
2    | right-left
3    | summerfivehigh
4    | up a right b left
```

I have a pandas series with the following words (note that 'fivehigh' is intentionally missing):

```
up, down, right, left, summer
```

I want to split out the rows for IDs based on the words in the series, like so:

```
ID   | Tag
1    | up
1    | down
2    | right
2    | left
3    | summer
3    | fivehigh
4    | up
4    | a
4    | right
4    | b
4    | left
```

Essentially I want to "split" tags if a piece of text they contain appears in the series.

Comment: simply submitting a set of requirements (and not very clear ones at that) is not likely to get you an answer. SO is not a free coding site. Please show what *you* have tried to do to solve this problem.

Comment: So far my "trying" has been searching SO/google for 30 minutes without being able to find any examples to work off of. Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: Oh, and please let me know what's not clear so that I can rephrase. It seems very clear to me but I can understand that maybe it's not to some. Thank you!

Comment: You are providing examples but not actual rules for the missing portions. What would you expect to get from something like `up a right b left`?

Comment: updated, thank you!

Comment: I meant in the dataframe, not the series.

Comment: I'm trying to teach you how to ask a good question.

Comment: haha now look who's not being clear! I'll edit it again ;)

Comment: Fair enough. You got me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `extractall` with a regular expression build from list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3],'Tag':['up down','right-left','summerfivehigh']})
l = ['up','down','right','left','summer']
rege = '(\w+)?('+'|'.join(l)+')(\w+)?'
df = df.set_index('ID')
df.Tag.str.extractall(rege).stack().reset_index([1,2], drop=True)
```

Output:

```
ID
1          up
1        down
2       right
2        left
3      summer
3    fivehigh
dtype: object
```

Comment: @NBC you are welcome.  Regular expressions.  Very complicated and powerful.  I am still learning.  Questions on SO help me practice.  I am not totally convinced this express is robust enough. However, I think it solves the problem for this test dataset.